# Windows 7 freezes while uploading files via broadband service ( Both downloads & mobile data transfers work )

Tags: windows

My windows 7 pc freezes when i try to **upload** something on the web, and it only happens when i use cable broadband connection.

Sometimes i can upload the file but most of time **( 8 out of 10 times )** it will freeze, to restart i need to switch off and on from main board.

**Note:**
When i connect my 3G phone to the PC it doesn't freeze, I am able to upload any file size.

Recently i formatted the computer and re-installed the windows 7, but it didn't solve the issue.

What could be wrong with the cable broadband, I am facing this ever since i get this connection ( 3 months ago ). Also, I would like to add that my pc does **not** freeze while **downloading.**

Please help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Diagnose** your broadband CPE-unit for any defective self-diagnostic warnings.

**Check** your Broadband service provider contract conditions vs. your real observations.

As you noted an 8/10 failure rate observation, namely check the (un)guaranteed ( real ) xDSL-Concentrator factor ( upStream grooming of 1:5, 1:10, 1:30, 1:50, ... make a big difference not only in PeakHour on upStream traffic shaping ( well, rather blocking...) )

**Test** your real achievable upStream speed against a few different speed test servers ( naturally do not opt to use your xDSL provider's own Speed Test Server, use rather another destination, outside of the control of the xDSL provider ).

**Collect** real achievable performance data -- several different Test Servers, a few dozens tests, round the 24/7 calendar to avoid objections on un-guarranteed performance and to be able to prove a reasonable and repetitive results for the non-compliance procedure in case the contracted terms & conditions are not fulfilled.